# grep without string

Tags: string, grep

I want to find all the lines in my text file containing the string `"abc"`, but not containing the string `"def"`. Can I use the `grep` command to accomplish this task?

Comment: It seems like you are using grep to help you navigate your way through a codebase; if so - I wrote a tool recently to help make that activity much easier: http://reviewboardstudents.wordpress.com/2012/10/22/ucosp-blog-post-sack-and-other-developer-shortcuts/ Hopefully it'll prove helpful for you as well

Comment: Great, I'll take a look!

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Either of the these will do:

```
grep -v "def" input_file | grep "abc"
```

or

```
grep "abc" input_file | grep -v "def"
```

The following will also preserve coloring if you only want to see the output on stdout:

```
grep --color=always "abc" input_file | grep -v "def"
```

The `-v` option (stands for "invert match") tells `grep` to ignore the lines with the specified pattern - in this case `def`.

Comment: Great, thanks! When my input_file is large, is there a difference in speed between your first and second code?

Comment: @MikaH. You can add `time` before each of the script commands to see how long each takes. I think there is only a negligible difference.

Comment: The part about preserving coloring is really useful. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

This might do it.

```
fgrep "abc" file | grep -v "def"
```